# Iterate through an array in PHP

Tags: php

I'm very new to PHP but I have to make something quickly.

```
 $fql = "SELECT uid, name, pic_square, sex 
         FROM user 
         WHERE uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me())";

      $response = $facebook->api(array(
           'method' => 'fql.query',
           'query' =>$fql,
         ));

    $allUsers = $mapper->getAll();
```

So I've got $response and, for example, `$response[0]["name"]` returns the name of the first user and `$response[0]["id"]` returns the id of the first user.

Then I've got the $allUsers array in which I've got all of the users ids. For `$allUsers[0]->id` returns the id of the first user.

Ok, now as the result I would like to filter the $response array and have in it only users whose id is present in $allUsers array. It may be new array, for example $filteredResponse.

Thank you very much for the help, it's really just an issue of me not really knowing the syntax

I wrote sth like this:

```
$filteredResult = array();

    foreach ($response as &$userfb) {
        foreach($allUsers as &$userdb){
            if($userfb["id"] == $userdb->id){
                array_push($filteredResult, $userfb);
                break 1;
            }
        }
    }
```

Is this correct ?

Comment: Do your homework: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask The PHP homepage has an excellent documentation. Here is the one on the `array_filter` function, which will do exactly what you want -- filter an array: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php

Answer (score 2):

Get use to this pattern you'll use it a lot.

```
// First for each loop takes each element of the 1st array and makes it a variable.
foreach ($response as resposeData)
{
   // the second foreach loop goes through the 2nd level array.
   // since it is a hash array we ask to give us the hash key and it's value.
   // This allows for us to use if conditionals to decide what to do with the data.
   foreach ($responseData as $key => $val)
   {
   }
}
```

Comment: I dont understand, could You please write the code to really do the filtering and return array ?

Comment: stackoverflow is not a place for you to get free code.  I gave you the skeleton to iterate through arrays.  I'll add some comments, but you'll have to read the php docs to work your way through it.